# Adding spinner dynamically

Tags: android, android-spinner

I am trying to add a new spinner to a LinearLayout using java on onItemSelected event of one spinner. Here is what my code looks like:

```
seriesspinner=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.series_spinner);
    seriesspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View item,
                int position, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                View dynamicPlace=findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinners_layout);
                String selectedItem=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().toLowerCase();
                ((LinearLayout)dynamicPlace).removeAllViews();
                if(selectedItem.equalsIgnoreCase("futures")){
                    Spinner expiryMonthSpinner=new Spinner(getApplicationContext());
                    expiryMonthSpinner.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)));

                    ArrayAdapter<String> expirymonth=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.expiry_month_array));
                    expiryMonthSpinner.setAdapter(expirymonth);
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), selectedItem, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();                        
                    ((LinearLayout)dynamicPlace).addView(expiryMonthSpinner);

                }
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

    });
```

But this thing is not working. Please help.

Comment: what means "not working"? Crashing, nothing happends? Is the Toast shown?

Comment: Yes toast is shown, but nothing happens... :/

Comment: print expiryMonthSpinner, if its null its not working, else it might be the layoutparam of some other element that prevent it from appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with my layout height and that was the reason the layout wasn't being displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Change     `seriesspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {`

to

```
seriesspinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new View.OnItemSelectedListener() {
```

Answer (score 0):

I have no compiler by hand currently, but maybe the view resource is wrong. The the following. simple_spinner_item and simple_spinner_dropdown_item needs to chang

```
Spinner expiryMonthSpinner=new Spinner(...)
ArrayAdapter<String> expirymonth=new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, getResources().getStringArray(R.array.expiry_month_array));
expiryMonthSpinner.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
```